# wxpython: 'Example' object has no attribute 'OnClick'

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am making a GUI of the periodic table of elements with wxpython, I have added all the buttons. So now what I want is when the user selects multiple buttons it should give me output same as the labeled on the button. Trying to run this code but getting the error. Don't know what's wrong, I am doing here.

```
import wx


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(1000, 800))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        p = wx.Panel(self)

        gs = wx.GridSizer(11, 18, 5, 1)

        A = ["H", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "He", "Li", "Be", " ",
             " ",
             " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
             " ",
             " ", " ", " ", " ", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co",
             "Ni",
             "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd",
             "Ag",
             "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "", "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au",
             "Hg", "Tl",
             "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", "Nh",
             "Fl",
             "Mc", "Lv", "Ts", "Og",
             " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
             "La",
             "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb", "Lu", " ", " ", " ", "Ac",
             "Th",
             "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
             " ",
             " ", " ", "Go", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
        for i in A:
            btn = str(i)
        a = wx.Button(self, 10, "str(i)", (20, 20))  # buttons are added
        a.myname = "str(i)"
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, a)
        print(i)

    def OnClick(self, event):  # When the button is clicked
        name = event.GetEventObject().myname

        p.SetSizer(gs)

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='Grid demo')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I would assume your indentation is wrong- make sure that OnClick is properly indented

Comment: Yup! Got it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the third argument in `self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, a)` is useless, try `self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)`

(comparing with code generated thanks to wxformbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

It's all a bit tight given the number of buttons and you must declare the buttons as part of the panel, not hope that the sizer will do the work for you.
There are few changes but they are important.

Code now includes elements{dictionary} for element display (I'm missing a few of the rarer elements like Oganesson but hey if you can't eat it, smoke it, make a purchase with it or use it to scale a mountain, who cares?)

```
import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (2000,1000))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.elements = {'Ru': 'Ruthenium', 'Re': 'Rhenium', 'Rf': 'Rutherfordium', 'Rg': 'Roentgenium', 'Ra': 'Radium', 'Rb': 'Rubidium', 'Rn': 'Radon', 'Rh': 'Rhodium', 'Be': 'Beryllium', 'Ba': 'Barium', 'Bh': 'Bohrium', 'Bi': 'Bismuth', 'Bk': 'Berkelium', 'Br': 'Bromine', 'H': 'Hydrogen', 'P': 'Phosphorus', 'Os': 'Osmium', 'Es': 'Einsteinium', 'Hg': 'Mercury', 'Ge': 'Germanium', 'Gd': 'Gadolinium', 'Ga': 'Gallium', 'Pr': 'Praseodymium', 'Pt': 'Platinum', 'Pu': 'Plutonium', 'C': 'Carbon', 'Pb': 'Lead', 'Pa': 'Protactinium', 'Pd': 'Palladium', 'Cd': 'Cadmium', 'Po': 'Polonium', 'Pm': 'Promethium', 'Hs': 'Hassium', 'Uup': 'Ununpentium', 'Uus': 'Ununseptium', 'Uuo': 'Ununoctium', 'Ho': 'Holmium', 'Hf': 'Hafnium', 'K': 'Potassium', 'He': 'Helium', 'Md': 'Mendelevium', 'Mg': 'Magnesium', 'Mo': 'Molybdenum', 'Mn': 'Manganese', 'O': 'Oxygen', 'Mt': 'Meitnerium', 'S': 'Sulfur', 'W': 'Tungsten', 'Zn': 'Zinc', 'Eu': 'Europium', 'Zr': 'Zirconium', 'Er': 'Erbium', 'Ni': 'Nickel', 'No': 'Nobelium', 'Na': 'Sodium', 'Nb': 'Niobium', 'Nd': 'Neodymium', 'Ne': 'Neon', 'Np': 'Neptunium', 'Fr': 'Francium', 'Fe': 'Iron', 'Fl': 'Flerovium', 'Fm': 'Fermium', 'B': 'Boron', 'F': 'Fluorine', 'Sr': 'Strontium', 'N': 'Nitrogen', 'Kr': 'Krypton', 'Si': 'Silicon', 'Sn': 'Tin', 'Sm': 'Samarium', 'V': 'Vanadium', 'Sc': 'Scandium', 'Sb': 'Antimony', 'Sg': 'Seaborgium', 'Se': 'Selenium', 'Co': 'Cobalt', 'Cn': 'Copernicium', 'Cm': 'Curium', 'Cl': 'Chlorine', 'Ca': 'Calcium', 'Cf': 'Californium', 'Ce': 'Cerium', 'Xe': 'Xenon', 'Lu': 'Lutetium', 'Cs': 'Caesium', 'Cr': 'Chromium', 'Cu': 'Copper', 'La': 'Lanthanum', 'Li': 'Lithium', 'Lv': 'Livermorium', 'Tl': 'Thallium', 'Tm': 'Thulium', 'Lr': 'Lawrencium', 'Th': 'Thorium', 'Ti': 'Titanium', 'Te': 'Tellurium', 'Tb': 'Terbium', 'Tc': 'Technetium', 'Ta': 'Tantalum', 'Yb': 'Ytterbium', 'Db': 'Dubnium', 'Dy': 'Dysprosium', 'Ds': 'Darmstadtium', 'I': 'Iodine', 'U': 'Uranium', 'Y': 'Yttrium', 'Ac': 'Actinium', 'Ag': 'Silver', 'Uut': 'Ununtrium', 'Ir': 'Iridium', 'Am': 'Americium', 'Al': 'Aluminium', 'As': 'Arsenic', 'Ar': 'Argon', 'Au': 'Gold', 'At': 'Astatine', 'In': 'Indium'}
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        gs = wx.GridSizer(11, 18, 5, 5)
        A = [ "H"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", "He", "Li", "Be"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", "B" , "C", "N", "O", "F" , "Ne", "Na", "Mg"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca","Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru","Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "" , "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs","Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", "Nh", "Fl", "Mc", "Lv", "Ts", "Og"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm","Yb", "Lu"," ", " ", " ","Ac", "Th" , "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk","Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md" , "No", "Lr"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," " ,"Go"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","ZZ" ]
        for i in A:
            btn = wx.Button(p, -1, i, (10,20)) #buttons are added
            btn.myname = i
            gs.Add(btn,0,)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn)
        p.SetSizer(gs)

    def OnClick(self, event):  #When the button is clicked
        name = event.GetEventObject().myname
        try:
            element = self.elements[name]
            wx.MessageBox("You selected element "+element, "Selection",wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.OK)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox("You selected element "+name, "Selection",wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.OK)

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title = 'Grid demo')
app.MainLoop()
```

New version based on your other question [Error with on click event in wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348606/error-with-on-click-event-in-wxpython)

```
import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (1400,500))
        self.InitUI()
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.elements = {'Ru': 'Ruthenium', 'Re': 'Rhenium', 'Rf': 'Rutherfordium', 'Rg': 'Roentgenium', 'Ra': 'Radium', 'Rb': 'Rubidium', 'Rn': 'Radon', 'Rh': 'Rhodium', 'Be': 'Beryllium', 'Ba': 'Barium', 'Bh': 'Bohrium', 'Bi': 'Bismuth', 'Bk': 'Berkelium', 'Br': 'Bromine', 'H': 'Hydrogen', 'P': 'Phosphorus', 'Os': 'Osmium', 'Es': 'Einsteinium', 'Hg': 'Mercury', 'Ge': 'Germanium', 'Gd': 'Gadolinium', 'Ga': 'Gallium', 'Pr': 'Praseodymium', 'Pt': 'Platinum', 'Pu': 'Plutonium', 'C': 'Carbon', 'Pb': 'Lead', 'Pa': 'Protactinium', 'Pd': 'Palladium', 'Cd': 'Cadmium', 'Po': 'Polonium', 'Pm': 'Promethium', 'Hs': 'Hassium', 'Uup': 'Ununpentium', 'Uus': 'Ununseptium', 'Uuo': 'Ununoctium', 'Ho': 'Holmium', 'Hf': 'Hafnium', 'K': 'Potassium', 'He': 'Helium', 'Md': 'Mendelevium', 'Mg': 'Magnesium', 'Mo': 'Molybdenum', 'Mn': 'Manganese', 'O': 'Oxygen', 'Mt': 'Meitnerium', 'S': 'Sulfur', 'W': 'Tungsten', 'Zn': 'Zinc', 'Eu': 'Europium', 'Zr': 'Zirconium', 'Er': 'Erbium', 'Ni': 'Nickel', 'No': 'Nobelium', 'Na': 'Sodium', 'Nb': 'Niobium', 'Nd': 'Neodymium', 'Ne': 'Neon', 'Np': 'Neptunium', 'Fr': 'Francium', 'Fe': 'Iron', 'Fl': 'Flerovium', 'Fm': 'Fermium', 'B': 'Boron', 'F': 'Fluorine', 'Sr': 'Strontium', 'N': 'Nitrogen', 'Kr': 'Krypton', 'Si': 'Silicon', 'Sn': 'Tin', 'Sm': 'Samarium', 'V': 'Vanadium', 'Sc': 'Scandium', 'Sb': 'Antimony', 'Sg': 'Seaborgium', 'Se': 'Selenium', 'Co': 'Cobalt', 'Cn': 'Copernicium', 'Cm': 'Curium', 'Cl': 'Chlorine', 'Ca': 'Calcium', 'Cf': 'Californium', 'Ce': 'Cerium', 'Xe': 'Xenon', 'Lu': 'Lutetium', 'Cs': 'Caesium', 'Cr': 'Chromium', 'Cu': 'Copper', 'La': 'Lanthanum', 'Li': 'Lithium', 'Lv': 'Livermorium', 'Tl': 'Thallium', 'Tm': 'Thulium', 'Lr': 'Lawrencium', 'Th': 'Thorium', 'Ti': 'Titanium', 'Te': 'Tellurium', 'Tb': 'Terbium', 'Tc': 'Technetium', 'Ta': 'Tantalum', 'Yb': 'Ytterbium', 'Db': 'Dubnium', 'Dy': 'Dysprosium', 'Ds': 'Darmstadtium', 'I': 'Iodine', 'U': 'Uranium', 'Y': 'Yttrium', 'Ac': 'Actinium', 'Ag': 'Silver', 'Uut': 'Ununtrium', 'Ir': 'Iridium', 'Am': 'Americium', 'Al': 'Aluminium', 'As': 'Arsenic', 'Ar': 'Argon', 'Au': 'Gold', 'At': 'Astatine', 'In': 'Indium'}
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        hbox1= wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.t1= wx.TextCtrl (p,0,value="",size=(120,30),style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        hbox1.Add(self.t1,proportion=0,flag=wx.CENTER)
        gs = wx.GridSizer(11, 18, 5, 5)
        A = [ "H"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", "He", "Li", "Be"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", "B" , "C", "N", "O", "F" , "Ne", "Na", "Mg"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca","Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru","Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "" , "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs","Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", "Nh", "Fl", "Mc", "Lv", "Ts", "Og"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm","Yb", "Lu"," ", " ", " ","Ac", "Th" , "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk","Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md" , "No", "Lr"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," " ," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
        for element in A:
            btn = wx.Button(p, -1, element, (10,20)) #buttons are added
            btn.name = element
            gs.Add(btn,0,)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn)
        hbox1.Add(gs,proportion=0)
        p.SetSizer(hbox1)

    def OnClick(self, event):  #When the button is clicked
        name = event.GetEventObject().name
        try:
            element = self.elements[name]
        except:
            element = name
        self.t1.SetValue(element)

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title = 'Element Grid')
app.MainLoop()
```

This is now the third time that I have asked you to read how StackOverflow works, please read the tour pages. Ultimately, this is for your own good.

Comment: when i click a button it prints  in the terminal instead of the panel ,can you please suggest me how can i get the clicked button label there itself on the panel. I am sorry very new to python.

Comment: That's what `print name` will get you. Have a look at the edited answer. It's a messagebox as the screen is already taken up with the element grid.

Comment: Module object has no attribute 'Frame '

Comment: Module object has no attribute 'Frame '. - attribute error

Comment: Sorry. I was having the same .py file. Now its working