# Error with on click event in wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to collect input from the user in test box. So when I click a button it should give me name of that button in test box
Error: you should omit either rows of column

```
   for i in A:


        hbox1=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)



        btn = wx.Button(p, -1, i, (10,20)) 


        btn.myname = I


        gs.Add(btn,0,)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn)


        self.t1=wx.TextCtrl(p)


        gs.Add(btn,0,)    


        self.t1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn)


        gs.Add(hbox1)

    p.SetSizer(gs)


def OnClick(self, event):  #When the button is clicked

    name = event.GetEventObject().myname
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **wx**.TextCtrl: `self.t1=wx.TextCtrl(p)`

Comment: and `btn.myname = i` not `btn.myname = I`

Comment: @phd still getting error: may be you should omit the number of rows or columns. Failed at Do insert(): too many items (181> 18*11). My grid has 18 columns and 11 rows.

Comment: @HimanshuPareek That code is not even in the question please read and digest https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Rolf of sexony  I am running this code in my python 2.7 . I want to collect input from user (when user will click the buttpn) in test box. I have used on click method with txtctrl  not sure whether this syntax is right ?

Comment: @HimanshuPareek Look at your original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306457/wxpython-example-object-has-no-attribute-onclick

Comment: Sorry  sorry! Thats fantastic. Working now